# Java sockets: Sending object properties instead of objects

Tags: java, sockets, networking, protocols

I made a client-server application which sends simple Java objects to a server and stores them there. However, serialization isn't really necessary in this context, because my objects only contain some strings and ints like name, phone number, address, age and ID. Sending strings is more complicated, because I need a reliable application protocol, but I'm not really sure how this is done correctly.

This is how I think it should work: I must inform the server what he receives, send the values in a strict order and send a message to tell the server that the transmission has ended. It would also be a good thing to send some kind of secret key at the beginning of the TCP stream to protect the server from unauthorized access. I would be very glad if someone could lead me on the right track.

Comment: You say *Sending strings is more complicated, because I need a reliable application protocol* **and then** *and send a string to tell the server that the transmission has ended* !!!

Comment: Even if you plan to send strings how are you thinking of doing that? you should share. For sharing data you can use standard protocols like, XML or JSON and using DELIMITOR you can mark the end of data.

Comment: I have been imprecise: Not a string, but a byte message.

Comment: This is a distinction without a difference. Serialization *is* sending the properties, along with the implicit `class` property. I don't see any actual question here.

Comment: I have read that serialization produces a lot of overhead, that's why I just want to send object properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client connects to server and uses DataOutputStream to send objects (as fields) and closes the stream in the end

```
dous = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
for(MyObject o : objects) {
  dous.writeInt(o.getId());
  dous.writeUTF(o.getName());
  ...
}
dous.close();
```

Server uses DataInputStream to read objects sent by client and determines EOS by EOFException

```
dis = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
try {
    for(;;) {
      int id = dis.readInt(o);
      String name = dis.readUTF();
      ...
      MyObject obj = new MyObject(id, name, ...);
    }
} catch(EOFException ex) {
        // ignore, client closed OutputStream
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That basically answered my question, but do you know how to prevent unauthorized access? Is a simple password/username combination a good approach? Of course everyone could read it, but it could be also encrypted afterwards.

Comment: password/username is good and simple to implement. You can also consider SSL